# Close context menu for Databound items in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu, datatemplate

I have listbox in my WP7 that uses the below `DataTemplete` to display the list items

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MetaDataTemplate">
            <Grid Width="440" Margin="4,12,0,12">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="download" Visibility="{Binding DownloadVisible}" Command="{Binding Download}"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="get link" Command="{Binding GetLink}"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete" Command="{Binding Delete}"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>                    
                <Image Height="64" Width="64" Source="{Binding Thumb}" Stretch="UniformToFill"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData.Name, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0" 
                           Style="{StaticResource MetaDataHeaderStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

defining the context menu data template makes it quite impossible to close the menu on pressing the back button! Does anyone faced this problem? How did you solve it?

I searched for the solution on internet, but couldn't find one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do it is to have a `ContextMenu` variable in the code behind, and have an event handler for the `Opened` event of the ContextMenu in the template.

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="stuff">

                            </toolkit:MenuItem>
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="more stuff">

                            </toolkit:MenuItem>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

In the `Opened` event handler, set the ContextMenu variable to that instance (i.e. sender).

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        menu = sender as ContextMenu;
    }
```

Finally, override OnBackKeyPress, so that if the variable is not null, and the menu is open, then close the menu and cancel the back event.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (menu != null && menu.IsOpen)
        {
            menu.IsOpen = false;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

    }
```

That should do it! Let me know if you have any issues, or need me to paste the full code.